# Element UI tags validation doesn't work in form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using element ui for vuejs. The element ui tags works fine, but when comes to validate the tag with the form item with prop property. Everything doesn't seem to work well. If the tag was empty, I click submit button, it will show tag must be required. When tag was inserted, the required text still appear.

```
<el-form 
  class="form"
  label-width="60px"
  :model="criteria"
  :rules="criteriaRules"
  ref="criteria" >

 <el-form-item label="Type" prop="type">
  <el-tag
    :key="criteriaType"
    v-for="criteriaType in criteria.type"
    closable
    :disable-transitions="false"
    @close="handleClose(criteriaType)">
    {{criteriaType}}</el-tag>
  <el-input
    class="input-new-tag"
    v-model="inputValue"
    ref="saveTagInput"
    size="mini"
    @keyup.enter.native="handleInputConfirm"
    @blur="handleInputConfirm"></el-input>
    <el-button class="button-new-tag" size="small" @click="showInput">+ Type</el-button>
 </el-form-item>

</el-form>
```

Comment: Would be nice to have the rest of the data (script part) and maybe a jsfiddle so people can help easier. Would give an answer but not sure what you want to validate here (the input or the tag count). Could you please make a fiddle with it ?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?